# How can I convert a for loop into a comprehension list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this piece of code :

```
 unique_char = np.zeros(26,dtype=np.int); 
    for char in s1:
        unique_char[np.int(ord(char)-97)] += 1
```

This is the entire code:

```
def check_permutation(str1,str2):

    if str1 is None or str2 is None:
            return False
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
            return False

    s1 = str1.lower()
    s2 = str2.lower()

    unique_char = np.zeros(26,dtype=np.int); 

    for char in s1:
        unique_char[np.int(ord(char)-97)] += 1

    for char in s1:
        unique_char[np.int(ord(char)-97)] -= 1

    for x in unique_char:
        if unique_char[x] != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

How can I convert this into a comprehension list?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be trying to count the number of occurrences of characters in a string - have you considered using a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: Can you paste full code and a description of the input/outpout you want ? What's in s1 ?

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't be efficient. When counting, don't use a list comprehension, use a `Counter()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  can you help with code?

Comment: @papey  can you help with code?

Comment: There's a much faster way to do this: `sorted(s1)==sorted(s2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided an example of `s1` so I've used my own. Starting with your code:

```
import numpy as np

s1='teststring'

unique_char = np.zeros(26, dtype=np.int)

for char in s1:
    unique_char[np.int(ord(char) - 97)] += 1
```

We get the result of a numpy array of

```
[0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

If you really wanted to do it as a list comprehension, you could do something like the following:

```
unique_char = [sum(1 for c in s1 if ord(c)-97 ==i) for i, x in enumerate(unique_char)]
```

Which would return the result of a list of the form:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

However, if you are counting characters in a string, the most efficient way would be to use a Counter.

```
from collections import Counter

unique_char = Counter(s1)
```

This returns a dictionary subclass of the form:

```
Counter({'t': 3, 's': 2, 'e': 1, 'g': 1, 'i': 1, 'n': 1, 'r': 1})
```

To apply this to the provided example, you could create a `Counter` for each string, and then check if each returns the same value for all letters:

```
from collections import Counter

def check_permutation(str1,str2):
    if str1 is None or str2 is None:
        return False
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False

    s1 = Counter(str1.lower())
    s2 = Counter(str2.lower())

    all_chars = set(s1.keys() + s2.keys())

    for k in all_chars:
        if s1.get(k, 0) != s2.get(k, 0):
            return False

    return True

print check_permutation('test', 'tset')
print check_permutation('test', 'tsat')
print check_permutation('test', 'tttt')
```

This prints:

```
True
False
False
```